# How do I prove this statement about the cardinalities of finite sets without using the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

If we were allowed to use the inclusion-exclusion principle:$|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$ then the question statement explicitly states that the two sets are disjoint, so this proof would be trivial.

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets.

Assuming for this part that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, and adopting the recursive definition of cardinality: (the empty set $\varnothing$ is finite with $|\varnothing|=0$. A set $S$ is finite with $|S|=n+1$, if there exists $s \in S$ such that $|S \backslash\{s\}|=n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We call $|S|$ the cardinality of $S$), use induction on $|B|$ to show that $A \cup B$ is finite and that

$$
|A \cup B|=|A|+|B| \text {. }
$$

Comment: One method that is used quite often to show the eqaulity of two sets is the double inclusion method. i.e showing that $| A \cup B| \subseteq |A| + |B|$ and show that $|A| + |B| \subseteq | A \cup B|$

Comment: Yeah, but the question says that we have to use induction on |B|. When I try this method, I can only think of using the inclusion-exclusion principle but that would defeat the entire purpose of the question.

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen: It should be $\leqslant$ instead $\subseteq$ and similar in the other case, of course.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. He's talking about double inclusion, and the subset symbol is the correct one.

Comment: @A.P. The subset notation is appropriate for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try an induction on $|B|$. More formally, let $P(n)$ be the statement “For all $B$ disjoint from $A$ such that $|B| = n$, $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$”. You should find that the inductive step and the base case follow from the two parts of the recursive definition of cardinality.

Edit: the base case $B = \emptyset$ is trivial. Now suppose $|B| = n + 1$. Then take $b \in B$ such that $|B \setminus \{b\}| = n$. Then we have $|A \cup (B \setminus \{b\})| = |A| + |B \setminus \{b\}|$ by the inductive hypothesis. And $A \cup (B \setminus \{b\}) = (A \cup B) \setminus \{b\}$. Thus, $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B \setminus \{b\}| + 1 = |A| + |B|$, as required.

Comment: It's trivial to prove the base case and to establish the inductive hypothesis, but then to prove P(k+1), I have to use the inclusion-exclusion principle which defeats the entire purpose of the question.

Comment: Inclusion exclusion is not necessary. I’ve edited my answer to include the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Outline: pick any member $b$ of $B$. Then use the inductive hypothesis on $A \cup (B \setminus \{b\})$, which inductively is finite and has size $|A| + |B \setminus \{b\}|$. Now add in $b$ again.